# Error running tensorflow in docker container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use Tensorflow module in a Python application running in a Docker container (actually I am using Keras but errors come from Tensorflow)

I have models (`.json` and `.h5` files) that I would like to load in order to use it :

```py
import logging
import os
from keras.models import model_from_json # library for machine learning
from numpy import array
import json

def load_models():
    global loaded_h_model
    global loaded_u_model
    global loaded_r_model
    global loaded_c_model

    modelPath = os.getenv("MODELPATH", "./models/")

    # load models
    json_h_file = open(modelPath+'model_HD.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_h_json = json_h_file.read()
    json_h_file.close()
    loaded_h_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_h_json)
    loaded_h_model.load_weights(modelPath+"model_HD.h5")

    json_u_file = open(modelPath+'model_UD.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_u_json = json_u_file.read()
    json_u_file.close()
    loaded_u_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_u_json)
    loaded_u_model.load_weights(modelPath+"model_UD.h5")

    json_r_file = open(modelPath+'model_RD.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_r_json = json_r_file.read()
    json_r_file.close()
    loaded_r_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_r_json)
    loaded_r_model.load_weights(modelPath+"model_RD.h5")

    json_c_file = open(modelPath+'model_CD.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_c_json = json_c_file.read()
    json_c_file.close()
    loaded_c_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_c_json)
    loaded_c_model.load_weights(modelPath+"model_CD.h5")
```

Here is the Dockerfile I use:

```
FROM python:3.7

# copy source code files
COPY machinelearning.py ./

# copy models files
COPY models/* ./models/

# install dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install h5py \
    && pip3 install tensorflow \
    && pip3 install keras

# run script
CMD [ "python", "./machinelearning.py" ]
```

But when I run the Docker container, I have the following Warnings/Errors:

```
2020-01-29 09:40:24.542588: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-01-29 09:40:24.542727: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-01-29 09:40:24.542743: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-01-29 09:40:25.394254: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-01-29 09:40:25.394289: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-01-29 09:40:25.394321: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (dd231f397f1f): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-01-29 09:40:25.394539: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-01-29 09:40:25.419513: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 1992000000 Hz
2020-01-29 09:40:25.420250: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55cab5bf9760 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-01-29 09:40:25.420299: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

I believe I need to install libraries or a different version of Tensorflow/Keras in my Dockerfile.

How can I solve this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: Hey, better have an "ENTRYPOINT" command instead of "CMD"

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you need to `COPY requirements.txt /to/destination`. your requirements.txt should contain **dependencies with the version number.**

```
FROM python:latest
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/code/
```

After that run

```
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Instead of below code in your Dockerfile

```
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install h5py \
    && pip3 install tensorflow \
    && pip3 install keras
```

I hope the problem will get resolved by mentioning version numbers in requirements.txt, not just --upgrade tag.

Also don't run upgrades if not needed.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I was using tensorflow 2.x and I downgraded to 1.15.2, the latest 1.x version. Now it works